# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7

When i try to build the application after getting done with the ui and inserting managed objects video i get an error saying:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x8664: "_OBJC_CLASS$THDiaryEntry", 
>   referenced from: l_OBJC$CATEGORY_THDiaryEntry$_CoreDataProperties in
>   THDiaryEntry+CoreDataProperties.o
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

also when i create a subclass of NSManagedObject my Xcode creates a

THDiaryEntry+CoreDataProperties.h and .m files which is different, the code for the respective files is as follows

```
    //THDiaryEntry+CoreDataProperties.m

#import "THDiaryEntry+CoreDataProperties.h"

@implementation THDiaryEntry (CoreDataProperties)

@dynamic body;
@dynamic date;
@dynamic imageData;
@dynamic location;
@dynamic mood;

extern NS_ENUM(int16_t, THDiaryEntryMood){
    THDiaryEntryMoodGood = 0, THDiaryEntryMoodAverage = 1,
    THDiaryEntryMoodBad = 2
};

@end

//THDiaryEntry+CoreDataProperties.h

#import "THDiaryEntry.h"

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface THDiaryEntry (CoreDataProperties)

@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString *body;
@property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval date;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSData *imageData;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString *location;
@property (nonatomic) int16_t mood;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

Comment: Is the file that implements `THDiaryEntry` part of the Xcode target?

Comment: i found the bug by mistake i had imported a .m file instead of a .h thank you